# on('change') function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, filter

So what I'm trying to do is update the '`topic`' selection based on what '`category`' a user has chosen.  What I'm trying to do is watch for a change event of the attribute '`data-curr_filter`' on the element with ID '`category-filter`'.  My jQuery for each category works as tested via web-inspector, so I believe it has something to do with the `.on('change')` portion of the function (it doesn't trigger the console.log). The code for this is as follows:

The HTML for search-filter:

```
<span id="category-filter" class="filter-select" data-target="filter_categories" data-curr_filter="all">
  All Categories &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>
filter by
<span class="filter-select" data-target="filter_topics">
  All Topics &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
</span>
```

The HTML for the 'topics':

```
<ul class="filter-list" id="filter_topics" aria-labelledby="filter_topics">
    <li data-val="affordability" data-cat="communities">Affordability</li>
    <li data-val="market_conditions" data-cat="communities">Market Conditions</li>
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("Hello Moto");
  $(document).on('change', '#category-filter', function() {

  console.log("Something change");

  if ($('#category-filter').attr('data-curr_filter') == 'all' ){
    $('#filter_topics li').show();
  }  

  if ($('#category-filter').attr('data-curr_filter') == 'communities'){
    //show all topics as a "blank slate" before altering the display elements according category
    $('#filter_topics li').show();
    //hide all the elements
    $('#filter_topics li').toggle();
    //show only the topics labeled with communities
    $('#filter_topics li[data-cat=communities').toggle();    
  } 
  ...
```

Comment: try ' $("#category-filter[data-curr_filter]").on('change', function() {

Comment: how do you intend to trigger an onchange event on a span tag ?

Comment: `onchange` is fired only when a value of an form control element changes.

Comment: The span class is within a form.

Comment: But it's not a form control element, like `select` or `input`.

Comment: Are you using a library that decorates the span so it becomes a select box? Please specify which library.

Comment: Ahh looking back at when I did successfully use .on('change'), it was watching input elements.

Comment: @teemu, I think the moment has come for your answer to be posted :)

Comment: @IvanRL: You can't initiate a change event on span since there is no such event associated to that type of element in jquery. However, you can do it manually, like this : https://jsfiddle.net/3pd9gzga/

Comment: Ahaha yeah I just re-read the documentation on it... 

"This event is limited to <input> elements, <textarea> boxes and <select> elements. "

Comment: @trincot Not yet, I think you're right, there's most likely a library behind. Libraries usually have implemented a corresponding event of their own.

Comment: @Teemu: By looking at the name of the classes associated to the DOM elements, it seems like a bootstrap.

Comment: Yeah we're using BS4 which I have zero experience with, I got it to work with BS3 with the .on('change') but one of the senior devs wants to roll with BS4

Comment: @IvanRL :  Seems like the code you posted here is the html generated by bootstrap. Rather than defining your own implementation, you should use bootstrap functions.

Comment: @DinoMyte : That didn't really help since I need the DOM to actually watch for event changes on this span class.

Comment: Just a hint, selector "#category-filter[data-curr_filter]" in .on() is unnecessarily complex and might be slow in some browsers. You can use #category-filter only, because there can't be more than one element with ID, so further filtering is needless.

Comment: Hey @micropro.cz : Yeah I realized while web-inspecting that it just gets the same element as #category-filter and the [...] is redundant.

I'm going to try make the span an input element and see what happens.

Comment: Also in matter of performance $('#category-filter').on('change', function(){...}) is better, because with this event pinned on document, browser will ask jquery on every change on every element if that changed element matches the selector.

Comment: Thanks for everyones advice.  Added an 'Answer' that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

ANSWER:

Just doing an onclick works... Kinda annoyed at how I completely overlooked this.

```
 $(document).on('click', '#filter_categories li', function() {
    var selectedCategory = $(this).attr('data-val');

    if (selectedCategory == 'all' ){
      $('#filter_topics li').show();
    }

    if (selectedCategory == 'communities'){
        //show all topics as a "blank slate" before altering the display elements according category
        $('#filter_topics li').show();
        //hide all the elements
        $('#filter_topics li').toggle();
        //show only the topics labeled with communities
        $('#filter_topics li[data-cat=communities').toggle();    
      }
...
```

TL;DR under my question:

Because it is a `<span>` and not an `<input>`, `<select>` or `<textarea>` element, it does not have the .on('change') event watcher. If I come up with an answer I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  //$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {

  console.log("Hello Moto");

  //$(document).on('change', '#category-filter[data-curr_filter]', function() {
  $('#category-filter').change(function() {

    console.log("Something change");

    if ($('#category-filter').attr('data-curr_filter') == 'all') {
      $('#filter_topics li').show();
    }

    if ($('#category-filter').attr('data-curr_filter') == 'communities') {
      //show all topics as a "blank slate" before altering the display elements according category
      $('#filter_topics li').show();
      //hide all the elements
      $('#filter_topics li').toggle();
      //show only the topics labeled with communities
      $('#filter_topics li[data-cat=communities').toggle();
    } 
    ...`
```

Comment: Hi Qiwen this doesn't work because change doesn't work on non-select/textarea/input

Comment: For those types you can try keyboard event like: `$('#id').keyup(function(){...});` , `.keydown(function(){...});` or `.keypress(function(){...})`.

Comment: I just used an .on('click') when selecting the Category as the trigger for the function